# Google play services login taking a long time

Tags: android, authentication, google-play-services

We use GPGS in out game and everything has been fine until we just launched the game. We have a couple 1000 active users, but I don't think that would overwhelm the system. The sign in process used to take about 10 seconds but now it just hangs when we try to sign in. It is only effecting some devices and sometimes effects our test devices, so it is not consistent. On Android we use the BaseGameUtils GameHelper's beginUserInitiatedSignIn() method, and neither of the callbacks get called. 
Is there anything we can do to debug this issue?

Note: We do have debugging enabled in GPGS but did not see any outputs.

Comment: Great question! I have found responsiveness of Google Play Games Services to be remarkably spotty in my own experiments in the last months. Hoping someone can shed a little light on this.

Comment: Run systrace on the respective method and see whats the cause of this delay as ecplained here: http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/systrace.html#app-trace

Comment: Hi @rioneye, did you ever find out what was causing this?  I'm also experiencing these issues.  When the user signs in, it used to take arout 10 seconds but as you say, now, it just seems to hang at various/random points throughout the  sign-in process.  If it's left alone, it does eventually connect, but it could be a *very* long time before that happens.